# Why is my NSDocument marked dirty after save?

Tags: cocoa

I have a Document based application with an undo manager.

I edit my document which adds stuff into the undo manager. This marks my document as "dirty" : [image: screenshot]

I save, and the data goes to the file which is fine. But the document is still marked "dirty".

I override :

```
- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
- (IBAction)saveDocument:(id)sender
- (IBAction)openDocument:(id)sender
- (IBAction)newDocument:(id)sender
```

and `autosavesInPlace` returns `NO`. Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I would start by checking to see if any of my undoable methods are being called after saving the file. Add breakpoints and verify none is accidentally called.

Comment: @insys following your suggestion, none of my calls to undomanager are called after save

Comment: Try a breakpoint on - (void)updateChangeCount:(NSDocumentChangeType)change;

Comment: @PierreBernard after my first action (that calls undo) `updateChangeCount` is called but when I save it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I added

```
-(IBAction) saveDocument:(id) sender {
   ...
}

-(IBAction) openDocument:(id) sender {
   ...
}
```

in my document and I shouldn't have done that. Implementing

```
- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
```

was enough and NSDocument takes care of everything